# Question about UIButton behavior inside collectionView cell in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I made the collectionView cell a dynamic type and put the information such as image, title, author and so on. This information is about the book, and we have created a "view" button at the bottom of the cell. When I press cell

```
if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
                let index = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first,

                let readBookController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ReadBookViewController {

                readBookController.bookNo = self.booksCategory?.books[index.row].bookNo
                readBookController.bookTitle = self.booksCategory?.books[index.row].bookTitle
            }
```

This code works fine.

But when I press the button inside the cell, the behavior when the cell is pressed (`let index = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems? .First) =>` This code does not run, it just moves the VC.

Is there a way to pass the same data to VC when the cell is pressed and when the button is pressed in the cell?

code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        switch (segue.identifier!) {
        case "TappedCellSegue":
            if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
                let index = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first,

                let readBookController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ReadBookViewController {

                readBookController.bookNo = self.booksCategory?.books[index.row].bookNo
                readBookController.bookTitle = self.booksCategory?.books[index.row].bookTitle
            }
        case "TappedBtnSegue":    // Not working
            let readVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReadBookViewController") as! ReadBookViewController

            if let navigationController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
                let index = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first,

                let readBookController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ReadBookViewController {
                readBookController.bookNo = self.booksCategory?.books[index.row].bookNo
                readBookController.bookTitle = self.booksCategory?.books[index.row].bookTitle
            }

            self.present(readVC, animated:true, completion: nil)
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: If tapping cell has the same effect as pressing button then simply make button disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cellForItemAt you can addTarget for button and give indexPath.row:

`cell.Button.tag = indexPath.row
 cell.Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)`

In buttonAction function:

```
@objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let index = sender.tag

    if let readBookController = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? ReadBookViewController {
        readBookController.bookNo = self.booksCategory?.books[index].bookNo
        readBookController.bookTitle = self.booksCategory?.books[index].bookTitle

        self.present(readBookController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```